# String. Replace function issue!

Tags: c#, asp.net

I think i need some help for the string replace function. This one do not replace and gives me same thing back. What might be the issue, guys?

```
FormattedURl = mysite.com/Merchant.aspx?1=lkdflfdfgj3242

lblclick.Text.Replace("<a class=linkclass href=http://www.mysite.com/ target=_blank >   </a>", 
"<a class=linkclass href=" + FormattedURL1 + "target=_blank ></a>");
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to assign the text back into the variable or control.

The replace function will return a string, not change the current instance.

```
lblclick.Text = lblclick.Text.Replace("<a class=linkclass href=http://www.mysite.com/ target=_blank >   </a>", 
"<a class=linkclass href=" + FormattedURL1 + "target=_blank ></a>");
```

Answer (score 4):

String is immutable, so all functions on string return new instances. Thus to see the effect of the function you must assign the result.

```
lblclick.Text = lblclick.Text.Replace("<a class=linkclass href=http://www.mysite.com/ target=_blank >   </a>", "<a class=linkclass href=" + FormattedURL1 + "target=_blank ></a>");
```

From the documentation of [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

> Returns a new string in which all
>   occurrences of a specified string in
>   the current instance are replaced with
>   another specified string.

Answer (score 1):

It does not modify the existing instance, it returns an instance with the changes.

From MSDN...

> This method does not modify the value
>   of the current instance. Instead, it
>   returns a new string in which all
>   occurrences of oldValue are replaced
>   by newValue.

Therefore you need to store the returned value and set it on your label or simply set your label to the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) is c# is immutable.  Thus, there is no way that `Replace` could change it in place.  Instead, it returns a new copy with the replacement done.